# scala compile server stopped due to inactivity | intellijIDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-compiler, user-inactivity

This never happened as I never turn off my pc. Seeing this message after recent update.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-223.7571.182, built on November 29, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.14 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
```

Comment: It's not clear: is it causing any issue? Might be better to open an issue to Jetbrains if you believe it's an issue.

Comment: If it's causing any problems, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=SCL.

Comment: Just restart Scala compile server

Comment: Nope it's not causing any issues.
I turned it off:-
```File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Scala Compiler | Scala Compile Server``` and unchecked ```Use compile server```

Comment: @Always_A_Learner I often debug macros with `scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-debug-lite"`. If I disable Scala compile server then upon re-compilation (Ctrl+Shift+F9) macro debug logs stop to be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK. If you want to change this behavior:

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler` -> `Scala Compiler` -> `Scala Compile Server` and there is an option `Stop if idle for` with a default 120 second value.

Comment: Kindly check my comment above.